# Blazor OAuth 2 with discord ! Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: .net, nginx, oauth-2.0, oauth, blazor

In a small Blazor Server project, I'm using OAuth 2 with Discord!
But, I face an unexpected situation! I can't solve it, after several hours of research and questioning ChatGPT!

The problem is simple, but the answer is not obvious to me.

I'm using a Razor view to redirect the user to Discord Auth.

here is Login.cshtml

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet()
        => await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Discord", new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host.Value}/callback"
            });
}
```

And there! Lots of mystery!!!

If I put this code locally! It does not work because I am redirected to callback without ?code and ?state! So I have a correlation error given that state is different on return .

But is I simply put
RedirectUri="/"

It works great! And I never go into "callback"!

Strange, because I did not fill in "/" in my authorized urls in the discord portal. but I thought to myself, it works so deploy!
I deployed to a Debian VPS via Nginx.
And there! ERROR !
Invalid_uri!

I understand !
I add "/"!
Always the same !

So I change

```
RedirectUri for RedirectUri="/callback"!
```

Local error! Invalid State! Yes I no longer receive the ?code&state!
I think it can work in production! Not invalid redirect_uri!

However in the Discord Dev portal, I have correctly filled in my domain https://ocalhost:5001/callback and https://modomaine.com/callback !!!!

I don't understand the behavior of dotnet at all on this subject!

The error is thrown by this framework handler!

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs

by .HandleRequestAsync.HandleRequestAsync

it's thrown away before I could get to the Blazor component

I tried to change the way i give the path i gave absolute path ! Relative path, i tried other way to redirect, i try without redirect instruction (infinty loopà)